# Test for SSL attacks - possible to extract certificate of server after SSLException?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, httpsurlconnection, sslexception

For a project, I want to test if anyone is tampering with the SSL connection. 
The `HttpsUrlConnection` is using a `SSLContext` with a pinned the certificate.

My question is: in case I get an **SSLException**, e.g. someones is trying to forge a wrong certificate, **is there any way to get details about that certificate?**

On a computer, using a browser (depending on browser and version) I will get a certificate warning and have an option to see details about the certificate.

I was wondering, if there is any way to get this using the `HttpsUrlConnection` or would there be another possibility?
`getServerCertificates()`will not work at this point, as the connection has not been established, and I see no other option..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that starting from Android SDK 22, the exception thrown already includes details about the certificate.

I could witness that devices running Android 21 would throw an `IOException` (Hostname not verified), while Android 22 is throwing an `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`, also giving details about the certificate.